# Adjust the width and length of footer and header

Tags: header-footer, footer

Hello can you help me i cant adjust the width and length of footer and header. The first picture is the probléme the seconde picture it's what i want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Page en tete

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{gray}{0.75}
\definecolor{myblueii}{gray}{0.75}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{gray}{0.75}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{% 
  \fontsize{50}{120}\color{myblueii}\selectfont%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\stepcounter{chapshift}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north 
  east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north 
 east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\addtolength{\titlewidth}{2pc}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\colorbox{myblueii}{\parbox{2cm}{\strut\color{white}\hfill\thesection}}}
  {1em}{#1}
  [{\titleline*[l]{\color{myblueii}\titlerule[2pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\addtolength{\titlewidth}{2pc}\normalfont\large\sffamily}
  {\colorbox{myblueii}{\parbox{2cm} 
 {\strut\color{white}\hfill\thesubsection}}}
  {1em}{#1}
  [{\titleline*[l]{\color{myblueii}\titlerule[2pt]}}]

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{myblueii}

\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}


\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{myblueii}%
\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth depth\headrulewidth}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1} 
{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\colorbox{myblueii} 
 {\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\strut\quad\thepage\quad}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=-1pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark 
 \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark 
  \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.9pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule} 
 {\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.9pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 1}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries Foot 2}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 3}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Je veux utiliser néanmoins des fontes qui « paraissent bien » en PDF
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

%% J'aime bien pouvoir contrôler mes hauts de page !
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Je veux pouvoir inclure des figures...

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%% ... des figures ``jpeg'' ou ``pdf'' ou "png"
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.png}

%% Je veux créer des Hyperdocuments
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=bl 
ue]{hyperref}

%% Je contrôle la taille de ma zone imprimée...
\usepackage{anysize}
%% ...en définissants les marges {gauche}{droite}{haute}{basse}
\marginsize{22mm}{14mm}{12mm}{25mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{28.44942pt}

%% J'inclue une bibliographie ; j'ai donc besoin du package natbib
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{bleuy}{rgb}{0.4,0.6,0.8}
\definecolor{blue(pigment)}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}
\definecolor{royalblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.14, 0.4}
\definecolor{oxfordblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.13, 0.28}
\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}
\definecolor{spirodiscoball}{rgb}{0.06, 0.75, 0.99}


\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % to insert PostScript figures  
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
      % new
      % new
 \usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}


\usepackage{booktabs, % new
            hhline, 
            makecell, % new
            multirow, 
            tabularx} % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % redefined

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}


%%%%%%%%%table size

%%%%%%



\lfoot{\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\small Année Universitaire 2017/2018}}}
\rfoot{\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\small Année Universitaire 2017/2018}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%% Voilà des hauts de page comme je les aime :
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection. #1}}
\lhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}}

\cfoot{}


%% Voilà mes légendes de figures comme je les aime :
\makeatletter
\def\figurename{{\protect\sc \protect\small\bfseries Fig.}}
\def\f@ffrench{\protect\figurename\space{\protect\small\bf 
\thefigure}\space}
\let\fnum@figure\f@ffrench%
\let\captionORI\caption
\def\caption#1{\captionORI{\rm\small #1}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%




%%%%%%%%Page garde
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\Large
\begin{center}



\vspace*{.06\textheight}
\textbf{\Large MEMOIRE DE PROJET DE FIN D'ETUDES}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\normalsize POUR L'Obtention Du Diplôme D'Ingénieur d'Etat}\\[0.3cm] % Thesis type
\textsc{\small Filière : Génie Informatique }\\[2cm]
\rule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.1mm}
\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\Large L'automatisation du suivi de la production sur OSIRIS PME }}\\[0cm] % Thesis title
\rule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.1mm}


\end{center}
\vskip1cm




 \begin{flushleft}
 \uline{\small {Réalisé par :} }\\[0.1cm]
  \textsc{\small {} }
 \end{flushleft}

 \begin{flushleft}
 \uline{\small { Soutenu le 03 Juillet 2018 devant le jury : }}\\[0.1cm]
  \textsc{\small {Mr.  : Professeur     
 Encadrant}}\\
  \textsc{\small {Mr.  Professeur à l}}\\ 
[3cm]
 \end{flushleft}



\clearpage






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table des matières :
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.30}\small \normalsize

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures 

\listoftables

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.18}\small \normalsize

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Introduction :
\chapter*{Introduction}


Bla

bla

bla

bla
\vskip3mm

blabla et rebla !
\vskip3mm

Et merci à Ludovic BUHLER pour son aide !..


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chap 1 :
\chapter{Contexte général du projet}
Ce chapitre décrira le contexte général du projet du stage qui s’est déroulé au sein .
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Présentation de l'organisme d'accueil}


   \subsection{Présentation général de IBM A \& T}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would easier to help you with a minimal example.

Comment: Of course my friend help

Comment: One solution is to NOT load fancyhdr until after \textwidth is set.  Another is to replace \headwidth with \textwidth wherever used.  Finally, your preamble REALLY needs to be cleaned up.  Throw out everything, one package or definition at a time, and see if you need it.

Comment: it remains the same problem, Help plz

Comment: If it coudn't work can you propose me another style of numbering, section and subsection !!

Comment: BTW, you load fancyhdr twice.  That was one of the duplicates that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This represents the minimum changes needed to fix the problem.  Please do not regard this as an endorsement.  I just don't have time to clean up the mess.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Page en tete

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{gray}{0.75}
\definecolor{myblueii}{gray}{0.75}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{gray}{0.75}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{% 
  \fontsize{50}{120}\color{myblueii}\selectfont%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\stepcounter{chapshift}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north 
  east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north 
 east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\addtolength{\titlewidth}{2pc}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\colorbox{myblueii}{\parbox{2cm}{\strut\color{white}\hfill\thesection}}}
  {1em}{#1}
  [{\titleline*[l]{\color{myblueii}\titlerule[2pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\addtolength{\titlewidth}{2pc}\normalfont\large\sffamily}
  {\colorbox{myblueii}{\parbox{2cm} 
 {\strut\color{white}\hfill\thesubsection}}}
  {1em}{#1}
  [{\titleline*[l]{\color{myblueii}\titlerule[2pt]}}]

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{myblueii}

\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1} 
{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Je veux utiliser néanmoins des fontes qui « paraissent bien » en PDF
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

%% J'aime bien pouvoir contrôler mes hauts de page !
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Je veux pouvoir inclure des figures...

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%% ... des figures ``jpeg'' ou ``pdf'' ou "png"
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.png}

%% Je veux créer des Hyperdocuments
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=bl 
ue]{hyperref}

%% Je contrôle la taille de ma zone imprimée...
\usepackage{anysize}
%% ...en définissants les marges {gauche}{droite}{haute}{basse}
\marginsize{22mm}{14mm}{12mm}{25mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{28.44942pt}

%% J'inclue une bibliographie ; j'ai donc besoin du package natbib
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{bleuy}{rgb}{0.4,0.6,0.8}
\definecolor{blue(pigment)}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}
\definecolor{royalblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.14, 0.4}
\definecolor{oxfordblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.13, 0.28}
\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}
\definecolor{spirodiscoball}{rgb}{0.06, 0.75, 0.99}


\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % to insert PostScript figures  
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
      % new
      % new
 \usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}


\usepackage{booktabs, % new
            hhline, 
            makecell, % new
            multirow, 
            tabularx} % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % redefined

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}


%%%%%%%%%table size

%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{myblueii}%
\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth depth\headrulewidth}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\colorbox{myblueii} 
 {\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\strut\quad\thepage\quad}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=-1pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark 
 \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark 
  \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.9pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule} 
 {\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.9pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 1}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries Foot 2}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 3}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\lfoot{\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\small Année Universitaire 2017/2018}}}
\rfoot{\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\small Année Universitaire 2017/2018}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

%% Voilà des hauts de page comme je les aime :
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection. #1}}
\lhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}}

\cfoot{}


%% Voilà mes légendes de figures comme je les aime :
\makeatletter
\def\figurename{{\protect\sc \protect\small\bfseries Fig.}}
\def\f@ffrench{\protect\figurename\space{\protect\small\bf 
\thefigure}\space}
\let\fnum@figure\f@ffrench%
\let\captionORI\caption
\def\caption#1{\captionORI{\rm\small #1}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%




%%%%%%%%Page garde
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\Large
\begin{center}



\vspace*{.06\textheight}
\textbf{\Large MEMOIRE DE PROJET DE FIN D'ETUDES}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\normalsize POUR L'Obtention Du Diplôme D'Ingénieur d'Etat}\\[0.3cm] % Thesis type
\textsc{\small Filière : Génie Informatique }\\[2cm]
\rule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.1mm}
\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\Large L'automatisation du suivi de la production sur OSIRIS PME }}\\[0cm] % Thesis title
\rule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.1mm}


\end{center}
\vskip1cm




 \begin{flushleft}
 \uline{\small {Réalisé par :} }\\[0.1cm]
  \textsc{\small {} }
 \end{flushleft}

 \begin{flushleft}
 \uline{\small { Soutenu le 03 Juillet 2018 devant le jury : }}\\[0.1cm]
  \textsc{\small {Mr.  : Professeur     
 Encadrant}}\\
  \textsc{\small {Mr.  Professeur à l}}\\ 
[3cm]
 \end{flushleft}



\clearpage






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table des matières :
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.30}\small \normalsize

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures 

\listoftables

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.18}\small \normalsize

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Introduction :
\chapter*{Introduction}


Bla

bla

bla

bla
\vskip3mm

blabla et rebla !
\vskip3mm

Et merci à Ludovic BUHLER pour son aide !..


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chap 1 :
\chapter{Contexte général du projet}
Ce chapitre décrira le contexte général du projet du stage qui s’est déroulé au sein .
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Présentation de l'organisme d'accueil}


   \subsection{Présentation général de IBM A \& T}
\end{document}
```